# Publishing a web application on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I want to publish an web application on Azure market place.

I can create a Linux VM, install Java, Tomcat, SQL server and create an  image of it. But instead of that, is it possible to create a tomcat instance along with database on Azure portal, add it to a resource group and publish this resource group on market place?

Would this approach be more advantageous?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace-publishing/marketplace-publishing-getting-started

Azure Marketplace offerings are based on Azure VM images or solution templates, your current solution would be the VM based route.  It sounds like you may want to look at the solution template route to leverage other capabilities such as Azure SQL Server.

Neither route enable "publish this resource group to the market place".  If that is the route you are aiming for that is essentially building out a multi-tenant application which is a bigger task and perhaps something like this link will help get you started:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/with-newly-available-services-azure-continues-to-be-the-best-place-for-software-as-a-service-developers/

There are also other stackoverflow answers which may be of help:

[Does a developer have to pay for publishing a SaaS app on Windows Azure Marketplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632728/does-a-developer-have-to-pay-for-publishing-a-saas-app-on-windows-azure-marketpl?rq=1)

[How can i publish my web solution to Marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301911/how-can-i-publish-my-web-solution-to-marketplace?rq=1)